# how to continuously add points and display it while a variable is false (js)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a game using HTML and JS that needs to continuously add points while the game isn't over and display it via document.getElementById(). What I expected was that every second 5 dollars would be added to the points and would be displayed in this sort of format: "Money: 5". All I have is "Money: ", so I figured there would be something incorrect with the javascript code that would keep adding 5 to the dollars. I did get an error message: "Uncaught Type Error: Cannot send property of innerHTML to null" I originally started fixing that problem using "window.onload = function()" but then the CSS of the page was damaged and completely off to what I had designed. Here is the code:

```
HTML:
 <h3> <b> Game Statistics </b> </h3>
  
    <span> Dollars Earned Per Second: <b> </b></span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span id = "money"> Money: <b> </b> </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span> Carbon Footprint Decrease Rate: <b> </b></span>
</div>
<div id = "garbagecan">
    <img src = "gbg.png" id = "gbg"> 
    <p> Garbage Can </p>
    <p> Status: Unlocked </p>
    <p id = "description">  0.1% decrease rate: $5 per second </p>
    <button> Increase to 0.5% decrease rate for $20 </button>

</div>

JS: 

const decrease_rate_required = 0;
var user_decrease_rate = 0.1;
var user_money = 0;
var tools_bought = 1;
var hasWon = false;

const garbage_box = {
   status: "unlocked",
   numOfUpgrades: 9,
   index: 0,
   currentDecreaseRate = 0.1,
   rateOfMoney: 5,
   maxedOut: false,
   decreaseRateUpgrades: [0.5, 0.6, 0.75, 0.9, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 1.85, 2],
   upgradeCosts: [ 20, 25, 30, 40, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 200]
}

while(hasWon === false) {
   user_money = user_money + garbage_box.rateOfMoney
   document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money: " + user_money
}
```

Comment: Running while loop without a proper timeout in place is recipe for browser crash

Answer (score 0):

1. I changed this `currentDecreaseRate = 0.1,` to this - `currentDecreaseRate:0.1,`.
2. The while loop is not what you need here. You would have to use an interval here to update values.

```js
const decrease_rate_required = 0;
var user_decrease_rate = 0.1;
var user_money = 0;
var tools_bought = 1;
var hasWon = false;

const garbage_box = {
   status: "unlocked",
   numOfUpgrades: 9,
   index: 0,
   currentDecreaseRate:0.1,
   rateOfMoney: 5,
   maxedOut: false,
   decreaseRateUpgrades: [0.5, 0.6, 0.75, 0.9, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 1.85, 2],
   upgradeCosts: [ 20, 25, 30, 40, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 200]
}

setInterval(()=>{
// Check if hasWon is false
if(hasWon == false) {
// Update money
user_money = user_money + garbage_box.rateOfMoney
   document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "Money: " + user_money
}
// Run the function every 1000 milliseconds that is 1s.
},1000)
```

```html
<span id="money"> Money: <b> </b> </span>
```